# How to sort an array of objects using MergeSort in java without comparator

Tags: java, sorting, object, mergesort

I need to sort a huge array of objects. Each object contains a number. I need to sort it by that number, but I can't use a comparator. Is it possible to do it using a `mergesort` algorithm?

Comment: What do you consider a comparator? You cannot sort anything without comparing it.

Comment: Without this void java.util.Arrays.sort( Comparator<> )

Answer (score 0):

As long as each object has a way to be compared (typically done in a 'compareTo(T other)' function), mergesort is a viable solution.

EDIT: More thoroughly, it would look something like this:

```
public int compareTo(T other){
    if this.getNumber() == other.getNumber(){
        return 0;
    }
    else if this.getNumber() > other.getNumber(){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: The thing is that I need to use merge sort or any other sorting algorithm to be able to use multithreading later for better performance

Comment: I guess the one concern about mergesort in a multithreading environment would be space complexity. Typically, mergesort is quite quick but uses a lot of space so that could get dangerous. Alternatives depending on what you need to be sorting and how frequently you need to be adding new elements would be either quicksort (longer worst case but is in place as opposed to mergesort) or insertion sort if you know the list is going to be almost always be sorted with elements being added only one at a time since that's a pretty good case for the algorithm. I added the compareto func if that helps

Comment: Space complexity doesn't need to be impacted by multi-threading. The same original array and temporary working array can be shared by multiple threads (same  virtual address space). For 4 threads, each array is split into 4 parts, then 4 sorts are done, then even and odd sub-arrays can be merged using 2 threads, and the final merge done using 1 thread.